# sencha display tooltip of a text field when it is in focus

Tags: java, extjs, gwt, tooltip, gxt

How do I display tooltip of a text field when it is in focus, not when mouse is hovering over?

I use TooltipConfig .

```
    TextField email = getEditor().getEmail();
    ToolTipConfig toolTipConfig = new ToolTipConfig();
    toolTipConfig.setBodyText("TEXT BODY");
    toolTipConfig.setAnchor(Style.Side.LEFT);
    toolTipConfig.setMouseOffsetY(0);
    toolTipConfig.setMouseOffsetX(0);
```

Answer (score 0):

Are you using extjs? If so, here's my answer:

You need to create custom tooltip to disable the default mouseover event.

```js
Ext.define('nutnull.ToolTip', function() {
  return {
    extend: 'Ext.tip.ToolTip',
    xtype: 'nutnull-tooltip',
    // Set this as emptyFn so that it will not create mouse event to show the tooltip
    setTarget: Ext.emptyFn
  };
});
```

Then you can override the textfield to show tooltip during focus event.

```js
Ext.define('nutnull.override.Text', {
  override: 'Ext.form.field.Text',
  tip: null,
  onFocus: function() {
    // show tooltip if exist
    if(this.tip) {
      if(!this.tipCmp) {
        this.tipCmp =  Ext.create('nutnull.ToolTip', {
          target: this.id,
          html: this.tip
        });
      }
      // Get the position of the textfield instead of mouse position
      this.tipCmp.targetXY = this.getPosition();
      // Adjust the position.
      this.tipCmp.targetXY[0] += this.getWidth();
      this.tipCmp.targetXY[1] -= (this.getHeight()/2);
      // Manually show the tooltip
      this.tipCmp.show();
    }
    this.callParent(arguments);
  }
});
```

In the textfield item, just add `tip: 'Sample Description'` config.

```js
{
  xtype: 'textfield',
  fieldLabel: 'Name',
  tip: 'Sample Description'
}
```

Comment: Im using gxt , but thank you very much for answer :) I resolved this problem :)

Answer (score 0):

I resolved this problem. I made new Tooltip object and wrapped tooltip config into this object.

```
TextField email = getEditor().getEmail();
ToolTipConfig toolTipConfig = new ToolTipConfig();
toolTipConfig.setBodyText("TEXT BODY");
toolTipConfig.setAnchor(Style.Side.LEFT);
toolTipConfig.setMouseOffsetY(0);
toolTipConfig.setMouseOffsetX(0);
Tooltip tooltip = new ToolTip(email,toolTipConfig);
tooltip.show();
```